# C++ : good practice of declare map of custom type

Tags: c++, pointers, treenode

I am trying to define a map like below within my `MyTreeNode` class:

```
std::unordered_map<int, MyTreeNode> children_map;
```

This seems to be fine. However, I am wondering would it be better to define the map using the pointer like?

```
std::unordered_map<int, MyTreeNode*> children_map;
```

For my specific case, I have

```
class MyTreeNode {
    // some code
    std::unordered_map<int, MyTreeNode> children_map; // line_1
    // std::unordered_map<int, MyTreeNode*> children_map; // line_2

}
```

Is there a good practice for such scenario? Should I use line_1 or line_2? Thanks!

Comment: That depends entirely on the context. If you already have the instances of `MyTreeNode` stored e.g. in a vector and only want to use the `std::unordered_map` as a kind of index into the vector then use the second version. If the map owns the `MyTreeNode` instances then use the first version.

Comment: @edamame - Um..... Is this supposed to be a map that holds **custom** types, or is it some device that holds entities **in special clothing**?

Comment: @enhzflep it is a map that holds custom types. Thanks!

Comment: If you are able to do either then use the first one (don't use pointers if you don't have to). Otherwise they have different uses.

Comment: I would prefer line_1 over line_2, but there is implicit storage overhead with using an `unordered_map`. If there are fixed number of children (perhaps a fixed max), using a plain `vector` may be better. If there are dynamic number of children, you might consider `map` instead, since it will have lower storage overhead if you usually have only a few nodes. Can you explain more what your tree characteristics are?

Comment: @jxh I am creating a search tree, which could go around 10 level depths and each node has 0-9 children (in the children_map).

Comment: If you are relying on `unordered_map` for your search tree, why not just use a single `unordered_map` for all of your nodes? What advantage does a tree structure give you for children that a single `unordered_map` would not be able to provide?

Comment: @jxh because the size of the map in each node has the same key

Comment: Line 2 should never be used unless the map is just a view and even then it is fraught with problems..  If the map is responsible for the node then use 1 or `std::unordered_map<int, unique_ptr<MyTreeNode>>` or `std::unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<MyTreeNode>>`

Comment: If you’re thinking that a (C-style) tree would have `Node*` members in a `struct Node`, just know that any container acts like a pointer in that it might store 0 or more children.  It’s therefore already appropriate even with no actual pointer type visible.